# DateTime Format Culture Converter

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, xaml

I try to implement **DateTimeFormatCultureConverter** to the `DataGridTextColumn`.

It works and I can debug it but **it doesn't change the DateTime format at all.** So I cannot see any visible changes...

(I can always use `return formated; // DateTime.Parse(formated);`
But in that case to sort field by ASC/DESC doesn't work.)

Any clue why?

Thank you!

**CODE**

```
public class DateTimeFormatCultureConverter: IValueConverter
{

public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
     {
           DateTime originalValue = (DateTime)value;

           CultureInfo currentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;

           if (currentUICulture.EnglishName.Contains("Spanish") || currentUICulture.EnglishName.Contains("Portuguese"))
           {
                string formated = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", originalValue.Day, originalValue.Month, originalValue.Year);
                return DateTime.Parse(formated);
           }
           else
           {
                string formated = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", originalValue.Month, originalValue.Day, originalValue.Year);
                return DateTime.Parse(formated);                  
            }
   }

   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
   {
       throw new NotImplementedException();
   }
}
```

**DataGrid**

```
<sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="txcInstalled" 
CanUserReorder="True" 
CanUserResize="True" 
CanUserSort="True" 
Width="Auto" 
Binding="{Binding Installed, Converter={StaticResource DateTimeFormatCultureConverter}}"
IsReadOnly="True" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning a `DateTime` variable, instead of the formatted string.  Remove the `return DateTime.Parse(formated);`, and instead `return formated;`.  That should do the trick for you.

**Edit** Without using a value converter, you can instead use the `StringFormat` Binding property.  See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2008/05/29/trying-out-binding-stringformat.aspx

The following should give you a culture-specific string, which is what you are looking for, I think:

```
<sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="txcInstalled" 
CanUserReorder="True" 
CanUserResize="True" 
CanUserSort="True" 
Width="Auto" 
Binding="{Binding Installed, StringFormat={}{0:d}}"
IsReadOnly="True" />
```

Comment: Correct. I can always use return formated; // DateTime.Parse(formated); But in that case to sort field by ASC/DESC doesn't work.

Comment: Ah.  Missed that in your question.

Comment: Well.. I've tried  Binding="{Binding Installed, StringFormat='{}{0:d}'"   and it is not working.

Comment: What is the error?  I don't think the single quotes need to be there.

Comment: Well... Without  single quotes there is a syntax error. So it doesn't build the app.

Comment: Oh, I see it... Missing the closing `}`.